# Difference between two results in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to find difference between my two query results. Following are my queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
    transaction
WHERE
    last_local_call_time >= '2022-03-04 00:00:00'
    AND last_local_call_time < '2022-03-05 00:00:00';
```

Result 1:

```
 Total  
--------
  213966
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
    transaction
WHERE
    modify_date >= '2022-03-04 00:00:00'
    AND modify_date < '2022-03-05 00:00:00';
```

Result 2:

```
 Total  
--------
  877349
```

I want to find Query1-Quer2 results (not row count but content). Following is one of my many failed attempts:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction
WHERE VALUE IN (SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE modify_date >= '2022-03-04 00:00:00' AND modify_date < '2022-03-05 00:00:00';)
AND NOT IN (SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE last_local_call_time >= '2022-03-04 00:00:00' AND last_local_call_time < '2022-03-05 00:00:00';)
```

Any assistance would be appericiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a where clause which includes the first query but excludes the second:

```
SELECT *
FROM `transaction`
WHERE last_local_call_time >= '2022-03-04 00:00:00' AND
      last_local_call_time < '2022-03-05 00:00:00'  AND
      (modify_date < '2022-03-04 00:00:00' OR
       modify_date >= '2022-03-05 00:00:00');
```